# In a two column documment, figure* and figure are placed non consecutively

Tags: floats, two-column

I am using the `sigplanconf` docummentclass, which has a two column layout. The environment `figure` inserts a figure in one column while `figure*` insert the figure covering two columns. The problem is that sometimes a `figure*` will not fit in one page, so LaTeX move it to another place, even before some `figure` in one column, which results in a document with non-consecutive figures.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{sigplanconf}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{figure*}
  \lipsum[1]
  \caption{This is the first figure}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \lipsum[1]
  \caption{This is the second one}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Figure 2 appears in the first page while Figure 1 appears in the second.

The question is: How do I solve this? I want to have the figures placed consecutively (I have 14 figures in a 11 pages document, if they are not consecutive, it is a mess).

By the way, the same happens with `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`, so it is not a problem of the class.

Comment: This bug was fixed in the 2015/01/01 release, if you have an older latex add `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` as a first line

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. I would thought that having Arch Linux was enough to be up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in the 2015/01/01 release, if you have an older latex add

```
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
```

as a first line.